Горизонтальный скролл в мобильной версии
Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать такую вещь: на моём сайте присутствует довольно большая таблицы и надо сделать так что бы на мобильной версии сайта элементы не сжимались, а появлялся горизонтальный скрол. Как это можно сделать?

На самом деле уже есть в bootstrap такой класс table-responsive, который отвечает за это. Суть в том, что бы оборачиваете table в table-responsive


td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
}

table {
  display: table;
  width: 700px;
}

.table-responsive {
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Таблица Таблица Таблица Таблица Таблица Таблица Таблица Таблица Таблица Таблица</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>




$(".table-responsive").each(function () {$(this).wrap("");});  - нашёл даже код, который я использую на некоторых сайтах, что бы любые таблицы были адаптивными и заполняющему контент не приходилось постоянно оборачивать таблицу.
